# Почему получается такой результат?

Tags: javascript

Почему получается такой результат.

Вот код:

```js
var x = 10;
var y = 5

console.log(x -= y += 5);
```

Объясните пожалуйста по порядку почему получается **0** ? Я думал будет **10**.

Comment: Hет уж. Это Вы сначала объясните, почему Вы дyмали, что будет 10.

Comment: Видимо, потому что справа налево присваивания выполняются.

Comment: я не понимаю, почему такое не было запрещено на уровне языка...

Comment: Операторы присваивания являются право-ассоциативными

Comment: Может кто-нибудь написать как это выражение будет выглядеть в цифрах? Например: 10-5+5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var x = 10;
var y = 5;

x -= y += 5;
```

---

```
var x = 10;
var y = 5;

y += 5; // 1. y = 10
x -= y; // 2. x = 0
```